# Rendering issue of jqx grid in Firefox and safari browser

Tags: angular, jqxgrid, jqxwidgets

[image]
jqx grid is working properly in the chrome and edge but has issue in firefox and safari, I think it is z-index issue but not sure why it works for chrome and edge browser, if someone has the idea what to do about this issue please suggest the solution. from the below images you can see what is the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We face the same issue.The solution is to reduce `z-index`. You may include following code in your custom css file. Class being applied is `jqx-grid-content`. So change `z-index` in that.

```
.jqx-grid-content {
  z-index: 300 !important;
}
```